# Servlet constructor and init() method

Tags: servlets, init

Why do we need an init() method in servlet? Can't we use the constructor to initialization?

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276082/constructor-in-servlet/2659597#2659597).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because Servlet is an interface, not an abstract class.  Constructor arguments cannot be specified on an interface, so the ServletContext needs to be specified on a normal method signature.

This allows the application server to know how to initialize any Servlet implementation properly.

Another solution would have been to require, but not enforce at compile time, a constructor taking ServletContext.  The application server would then call the constructor via reflection.  However, the designers of the Servlet specification did not chose this path.