# What is the use of init() method?

Tags: servlets, init

When servlet is initialised, init() method is called which initialize objects. What is the use of init() method when both constructor and init() serves the same purpose i.e initialization of object

Comment: In Init() method can be do initialization of some object like a database.  Maybe a simple tutorial as http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-life-cycle.htm can clarify.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381356/why-we-use-init-rather-constructor The accepted answer, answers your question too.