# Advantages/disadvantages of init method

Tags: java

What are the advantages/disadvantages of init method over a constructor in java? They both have the same purpose. How to choose between them?

```
public class A {    
  private int x;

  public A(int x){
    this.x = x;
  }

  public void init(int x){
   this.x = x;
  }
}
```

Here we can use either constructor or init method.

Comment: "they both have the same purpose", no they don't. you'll always need a constructor. an init method can come in handy if all your constructors contain identical code, but then I would recommend making it private, so that a subclass won't change it.

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong. They do **not** have the same purpose.

A constructor is **always** required when you want to create a new object using the `new()` operator.

A init method is something that *might* make sense in certain contexts, for example servlet stuff (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381356/why-we-use-init-rather-constructor) for further reading regarding this aspect).

And please note: in your example, one could your init method more as a **setter** - as it is simply *setting* the corresponding field.

Coming from there:

- first of all, you think about the constructors that you want to put into you class (by asking: which information is required to create a **new** instance of the class)
- if there is **special** need, then consider adding setters for specific fields - or as layed out above, it might be required to provide an `init()` method (in case where object **creation** and **initializiation** can not happen at the same point of time)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree with what you are saying. My question is both init method and parameterized constructor is used for initializing an object.

Comment: Which one you prefer ? and why?

Comment: I think I answered both questions. You start with one or more constructors. You use init methods if you have to. That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is not a regular method. It's special in a sense that it gets **always** called when you invoke `new A()`. If you don't provide a constructor, Java creates one automatically. As a consequence, constructors do not have a `return` (i.e. they return `this`) and always have the same name as the class.

On the other hand, `init` is a regular method, which you can call - or not. There is no universally accepted consensus for any kind of "init" methods. So it depends on what you want to do. If you want to ensure that the `new` calls your logic, use constructor. If you want to have your own stuff, use plain methods. You can mix and match, just be sure to write a **good documentation** about how your class is supposed to be used.