# Is it necessary to use init() in every servlet I use in my web application?

Tags: jsp, servlets, init

I have a JSP/Servlet web application with some JSP pages and servlets. I have read the following questions:

1. [Servlet constructor and init() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143386/servlet-constructor-and-init-method)
2. [Using special auto start servlet to initialize on startup and share application data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-init-servlet)

They were very helpful, but I have a new question: do I need to initialize every servlet I use? Or do I have to `init()` only the first serlvet that is called in my web application?

Comment: Your servlet will be initialized on very first request by web container.You really dont need to override init()

Comment: Override init() in case if you need to do some initialization task e.g  creating db connection or initializing some resources.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Servlet container controls the initialization of your Servlet, you don't have a choice but to use the `init()` method to initialize any instance fields that your Servlet might need. For example if your Servlet depended on a Service class to interact with some resource, you could do the following

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private MyService myService;

    public void init() {
        myService = new MyService();
        myService.setSomeProperty("propertyValue");
    }
    ...
}
```

This way you can initialize any fields. If you need it, you can use the `init(ServletConfig)` method instead or call `getServletConfig()` to access the `ServletContext` which may contain attributes that were added either from other Servlet `init()` or from `ServletContextListener`s. [Note that you can set in which order your Servlets will be initialized.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809775/what-does-the-servlet-load-on-startup-value-of-0-zero-signify)

Answer (score 0):

It look like that you completely misunderstood the purpose of servlet's `init()`. You seem to think somehow that you **must** override it. This is completely untrue. It just gives you the *opportunity* to declare a servlet method which should be invoked only once on servlet's initialization during application's startup. Usually, to initialize some local variables based on some services or configuration files or servlet's own `<init-param>`. Please note, *local* variables, thus the ones specific to the servlet instance itself which are declared `private` and are *never* shared/accessed elsewhere outside the servlet.

Particularly the following statement

> *Or i have to init() only the first serlvet that is called in my web application?*

suggests that you're actually looking for an application-wide hook which is invoked during application's startup. In that case, you should be using a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) instead of servlet's `init()` as answered in the [Using special auto start servlet to initialize on startup and share application data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-init-servlet) question. Here's a Servlet 3.0 compatible kickoff example without the need to add a `<listener>` entry to `web.xml`:

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's startup.
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's shutdown.
    }

}
```